# When does $\| \Pi \|_1 = 1$ where $\Pi$ is a projection.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

By projection I mean any matrix such that $\Pi = \Pi^2$. It is well known that all projections can be written as $\Pi = A(B^\top A)^{-1}B^\top$ for some $A,B$.

Characterize the class of projections (in terms of $A$ and $B$) for which we have $\|\Pi\|_1 = 1$. Here $\| \cdot \|_1$ is the matrix norm induced by the vector norm $L_1$ i.e. the max of the column sums of absolute values.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thanks. I corrected the question. The class of valid $\Pi$s is certainly larger than permuted diagonal matrices - consider the orthogonal projection on $1$ (i.e. the vector of all ones).

Comment: Two thoughts: (1) $\Pi$ may take an unfamiliar form. E.g. $\pmatrix{1&0&a\\ 0&1&b\\ 0&0&0}$ with $|a|+|b|\le1$. (2) It may (or may not) be easier to think in terms of $P=\Pi^T$ and $\|P\|_\infty$ instead of $\Pi$ and $\|\Pi\|_1$.

Comment: If $\Pi$ was restricted to the lower triangular Schur form, then it would be easier: $\Pi=\pmatrix{I&0\\B&0}$ with $\|B\|_1\leq 1$.